# No module named 'qiskit_metal'

Tags: qiskit

When I just want to import qiskit_metal, and it can't found it. Should install something? There is the wrong
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
import qiskit_metal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit_metal'

Comment: Have you installed it? Follow these instructions - https://qiskit.org/documentation/metal/installation.html

Comment: OK! I will try to work this.